# How can I confirm if a transaction has happened on Solana using the transaction hash (signature)

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library, solana-transaction-instruction

The confirmTransaction method is being deprecated. Instead there's a sendandconfirmtransaction method but that is not available on the connection object, so I can't use for transactions that are to be signed using phantom.

I have a transaction hash(signature) after the transaction so I'm trying to confirm if a transaction was done on the backend using the transaction hash, how is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

```
/** @deprecated Instead, call `confirmTransaction` using a `TransactionConfirmationConfig` */
```

Method is not deprecated try this:

```
const tx = await connection.requestAirdrop(publicKey, 1e9);
const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

await connection.confirmTransaction({
  blockhash: latestBlockHash.blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockHash.lastValidBlockHeight,
  signature: tx,
});
```